# How do I handle missing values when creating a class object?

Tags: ios, json, swift, option-type

Let's say I have a class called person:

```
class Person: NSObject {
    let name:String
    let gender:String
    let age:Int

    init(name: String, gender: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
    }

    class func createPerson(person:[String:AnyObject]) -> Person {
        let name = person["name"] as? String
        let gender = person["gender"] as? String
        let age = person["age"] as? Int

        return Person(name: name!, gender: gender!, age: age!)
    }
}
```

I retrieve data from a json endpoint that I want to convert into objects of class "Person". I use the class function "createPerson" to do that.

What's the best way to handle cases in which the url endpoint is missing a value?

As my code currently stands, this line will crash the program if one of the values is missing:

```
return Person(name: name!, gender: gender!, age: age!)
```

I know it's because I'm force unwrapping the variables, but how should I structure my code to account for the fact that a variable value may be missing?

**Should I declare everything as an optional?**

```
let name:String?
let gender:String?
let age:Int?

init(name: String?, gender:String?, age:Int?) {
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.age = age
}
```

Advice is appreciated. Thanks you!

Comment: you can use use ObjectMapper and no need to declare as optional there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to write class functions and create a custom init:

```
let entity = Person()
if let name = person["name"] as? String {
    entity.name = name
}
if let gender = person["gender"] as? String {
    entity.gender = gender
}
if let age = person["age"] as? Int {
    entity.age = age
}
```

Comment: @user3353890 Nope. Custom init doesn't make your code cleaner, unless you're initializing an object in multiple places in the project.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example for you using object mapper

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class PersonMapping: Mappable {

// MARK: - Variables & Constants    

var name : String
var gender : String
var age : Int

required init?(_ map: Map) {

 name = ""
 gender = ""
 age = 0

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    name                    <- map["name"]
    gender                  <- map["gender"]
    age                     <- map["age"]

}
}
```

and the you can use it as

```
// result is your JSON object 
if let data = Mapper<PersonMapping>().map(result){
                print(data.name)
                print(data.gender)
                print(data.age)

            }
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: thanks for the answer! I chose to go with the method below, but i appreciate your time and work! :)